# In Fullcalendar, is it possible to prevent event 'foo' to overlap with event 'bar', but allow it to overlap with event 'quux'?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Say I have 3 event types in Fullcalendar, 'foo', 'bar' and 'quux'. 'foo' and 'bar' can not overlap eachother, however 'quux' may overlap both 'foo' and 'bar'.

Is this possible? If so, how do I achieve this?

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOverlap says it is possible to prevent overlap, however this prevents overlap for the eventtype completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [eventOverlap](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOverlap) documentation page you linked to says

> "If given a function, the function will be called every time there is
>   a pair of intersecting events, whether upon a user drag or resize. The
>   function must return true if the overlap should be allowed and false
>   otherwise"

So within that function you can define any logic you like to decide whether the overlap is allowed, including checking the properties of the event. So you could write code which checks whether the two events are "foo" and "bar" or not, and then returns a response accordingly.

Naive example:

```
eventOverlap: function(stillEvent, movingEvent) {
  if (
    (stillEvent.title == "foo" && movingEvent.title == "bar")
    ||
    (stillEvent.title == "bar" && movingEvent.title == "foo")
  ) 
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```